# Уточнение по поводу posix_threads в linux

Tags: linux, c, многопоточность, pthread

Хотел разобраться что за легковесные потоки, в итоге полнейшая каша в голове стала еще гуще... читал тут книгу У. Ричард Стивенс, Стивен А. Раго "UNIX. Профессиональное программирование", там был кусок:

```
pthread_t ntid;
void
printids(const char *s)
{
    pid_t pid;
    pthread_t tid;
    pid = getpid();
    tid = pthread_self();
    printf("%s pid %u tid %u (0x%x)\n", s, (unsigned int)pid,
       (unsigned int)tid, (unsigned int)tid);
}
void* thr_fn(void *arg)
{
printids("новый поток: ");
return((void *)0);
}
int
main(void)
{
    int err;
    err = pthread_create(&ntid, NULL, thr_fn, NULL);
    if (err != 0)
        err_quit("невозможно создать поток: %s\n", strerror(err));
    printids("главный поток:");
    sleep(1);
    exit(0);
}
```

И в `linux` это выводило следующее:

```
$ ./a.out
новый поток:   pid 6628 tid 1026 (0x402)
главный поток: pid 6626 tid 1024 (0x400)
```

Т.е. для каждого потока `process id` разные из-за того что при `pthread_create` используется системный вызов `clone()` типа это тоже своеобразный процесс... И в итоге теперь не понятно: есть ли вообще в линуксе нити в общепринятом представлении, т.е. у нитей общее адресное пространство, но свой стек, у процессов разные адресные пространства.

Гугление очень запутало: где-то говорится, что `posix threads` в линуксе работают лишь в пространстве ядра, где-то, что в пользовательском пространстве, где-то, что и там и там. Я считал что в и там и там исполняются лишь процессы.

Посему вопросы:

- нативный тред в линуксе исполняется в пространстве пользователя или в пространстве ядра?
- есть ли вообще нативный тред в линуксе и является ли он легковесным процессом

Comment: странно это сколько ни запускал - номер процесса был одинаковым.

`vak@VAKVB:~/cpp/test-pthread$ ./q 
главный поток: pid 2314 tid 1179924032 (0x46543640)
новый поток:  pid 2314 tid 1190151936 (0x46f04700)`

`vak@VAKVB:~/cpp/test-pthread$ uname -a
Linux VAKVB 3.13.0-96-generic #143-Ubuntu SMP Mon Aug 29 20:15:20 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: @Vladimir, возможно ядро новое, там книжка старая... и это еще больше вопросов вызывает: как было, и как сейчас

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Да, есть *native threads* как результат вызова `clone()`, и они (в реализации *pthread*) исполняются в пространстве пользователя, являясь легковесными процессами (по крайней мере в том смысле, что кванты времени CPU им выделяются тем же планировщиком ядра, что и остальным процессам).

У каждого такого потока свой стек (в общем адресном пространстве), маска сигналов, переменная `errno` (и м.б. еще несколько ресурсов, см. подробнее в [pthreads(7) - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/7/pthreads)).

Comment: Стоит явно сказать что getpid() обязан одно значение возвращать согласно man pthreads, а не разные как в примере в вопросе.

Comment: И всё это вместе в линуксе называется костыль. Нативные (архитектурные) нити из известных сегодня систем, есть только SunOS.  Помню в ядрах <=2.4 линукса, трэды вообще можно было глянуть в ps ничем не отличались от процессов) Сегодня их там не видно, но при разработке костыльность вылезает сплошь и рядом)

Comment: @AnatolyY., а поконкретнее, чем именно потоки в Линуксе плохи?

Comment: @avp. Привет) Они не плохи. Они просто там интегрированы уже после того как архитектура ядра была сформирована и реализована. А это сразу же повлекло за собой ряд workaround решений. Это сразу видно при более сложной работе с ними. Например известная проблема "наследование" обработчиков сигналов в тредах линукса (в fBSD кстати тоже). Чего совершенно нельзя представить в той же SunOS где треды были спроектированы частью ОС с самого начала. Поэтому они не плохи, они просто своеобразны, я децл набросил, каюсь ;)

Comment: @AnatolyY., ага. Конечно, приятно, когда уверен, что сигнал обработается именно  в том потоке, где был заказан (и не надо играться с масками). Кстати, не скажете, а спецификации POSIX что говорят об этом?

Answer (score 4):

Я подозреваю, что вы имеете дело со старинными LinuxThreads или с какой-то попыткой эмулировать их поведение в целях обратной совместимости. Уже в версии ядра 2.6 линукс должен был перейти на NPTL (Native POSIX Thread Library), которая в соответствии с требованиями POSIX обязана возвращать одно и то же значение `getpid()` из всех потоков одного процесса.

http://www.drdobbs.com/open-source/nptl-the-new-implementation-of-threads-f/184406204

См. "Migrating to NPTL"

> - **`getpid()`** В LinuxThreads, в нарушение стандарта POSIX, системный вызов `getpid()` возвращает разные значения ID для разных потоков. NPTL исправляет это поведение.

Comment: Вообще-то, NPTL использует 1х1 модель

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov: Верно. Я, очевидно, неправильно понял Dr.Dobbs статью.